# Puppet claims to be unable to resolve domains even if domain properly resolves

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I have a fairly simple puppet setup, one master and one node, both running Debian Squeeze 6.0.4. I have DNS entries for the two machines, client and master respectively. Both client and master's DNS entries resolve correctly on both machines to the right IPs.

On my client, I have this configuration:

```
[main]
server = master.example.org

logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
pluginsync=true
templatedir=/var/lib/puppet/templates
```

Key exchange seems to fail, according to this messages in /var/log/syslog:

```
localhost puppet-agent[11364]: Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

Why is resolution not working only for puppet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a forward *and* reverse DNS entry for the client. You could also add an `/etc/hosts` entry for the client on the puppetmaster.

Comment: Brilliant. I will need to file in a support ticket for the PTR, but I will mark your answer as accepted if it works. (or if I test it with the hosts file beforehand)

Comment: Test with the `/etc/hosts` entry in the meantime.

Comment: Yep, ninja edited my comment to mention it.